# Bootstrap max width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use Bootstrap for my website. I want to limit the max width to 1000px for large desktops while maintaining the responsive layout. This is what I have currently:

```
body {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

But this doesn't work for navbar. Is there a way to limit the entire page to this width including navbar?

Comment: Try by setting this rule `width: 1000px;` to the navbar (maybe `.navbar { width: 1000px; }` do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead give the `.container` class a maximum width on larger screen and wrap your navbar inside a container

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
   max-width: 1000px; // or better set the width to 1000px
  }
}
```

Here is a full screen [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/02rb6rwL/embedded/result/)

Keep in mind setting the `.container` class to `1000px` will affect your entire site's width, if you wish to only have the `.navbar` fixed to this size then you can create a custom class and assign it to its parent container only.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.customclass {
   max-width: 1000px!important; 
  }
}

<div class="container customclass">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks raja. But this doesn't work when using fixed navbar (navbar-fixed-top).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!